# Why would a locked question be bumped to the home page?

Tags: discussion

This question was recently bumped to the home page, but is locked:

[Sound Request.  Young Kids Talking to Parent](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/14791/sound-request-young-kids-talking-to-parent)

As nothing can be done to the question, what's the point of it being bumped? Is this just a gap in the bumping logic?

Answer (score 2):

Unknown, but I nuked it.  Looking at it again, it really doesn't have much lasting value worth keeping around.